# How to use sql db or mysql db. without defining it in the database.yml

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

I was just wondering is there any other way to connect to mysql db or any other db without defining it in database.yml file ?

I know database.yml is used to setup the database configuration .But is that the only option available to connect to the database ?

Comment: you can do it by creating new object of mysql client, take a look here https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

Comment: Why do you need an alternate method? You can define more than one connection in that file if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveRecord anywhere

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_record"
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({:adapter=> 'postgresql', :user=>'foo', :password=> 'abc', :database=>'whatever'})
```